# Updating Entity Framework entity mapped to Postgres JSONB column does not update the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an `EF Core` project with `SomeEntity` entity as described on this page https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#poco-mapping in the `POCO mapping` section.
2. Add code that creates a new instance of `SomeEntity` and calls `SaveChanges()` to persist it to the database.
3. Add code that reads `SomeEntity` back (on a different instance of DbContext), updates it as follows `someEntity.Customer.Age = <different_number_from_what_it_currently_is>`, and calls `SaveChanges()`.

The expected outcome is that customer age will be updated in the DB, but actually no change happens. Looking at the entities in the `ChangeTracker`, I can see that `SomeEntity` is being tracked as `Unchanged`. To get the DB updated, I need to do update the whole `Customer`: `someEntity.Customer = new Customer { Age = <new_value>, <set all other props to old values>}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the IsModified property from the DBContext to the JSON column you wish to update, and then calling `SaveChanges()`

Here's an example:

```
_dbContext.Entry(SomeEntity).Property(x => x.Customer).IsModified = true;
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Tomi. I'm sure this will work, but the whole idea is that the expected behaviour is that if I made a change to an entity then it'll be tracked as Modified without me having to explicitly do anything. I raised this in the `Npgsql` repo but they have not replied so far.

Comment: I totally agree with you, it should be automatically tracked. I guess they are not tracking JSON changes probably because of performance reasons